# Rails and a development domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I'm trying to use http://ls1.bigseapreview.com as a domain for a Rails project. The problem is it doesn't seem to be correctly mapping any routing apart from the home page.

I have added /about but you can see that you will just get a 404, but it works locally.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your routing file?
+I added /about and it looks like it's working

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is a Rails project? Your "about" link points to "/about.php".